# min method in java keeps returning 0 after entering four values

Tags: java

The code I'm posting is actually a class of the tester code.  This is where I think the error is occurring, even though the output is not producing an error message.  The Math.min method is showing zero after four values are inputted.  It should show the smallest value of the four values.  What should I do?  Do I need to add lines or move lines?

```
public class DataSetMaxMin
{
   private int value;
   private int count;
   private int maxValue;
   private int minValue;

   public DataSetMaxMin()
   {
      value = 0;
      count = 0;
      maxValue = 0;
      minValue = 0;
   }

   public void addValue (int theValue)
   {
      count++;
      this.maxValue = Math.max(this.maxValue, theValue);
      this.minValue = Math.min(this.minValue, theValue);
   }

   public int getLargest()
   {
      return this.maxValue;
   }

   public int getSmallest()
   {
      return this.minValue;
   }
}
```

The tester program adds four values using addValue(). So if I enter 25, 15, 35, and 65, I'd expect the code to return the largest value 65 and the smallest value 15.

The actual result I get is 65 for the largest value and 0 for the smallest value.

Comment: Well, why do you think the minimum of 0 and 15 is? Why should it be 15?

Comment: It should be the minimum of the four values entered.  In this case, it should be 15.

Comment: But read your code. You're comparing 0 and 15, and you're hoping it gives back 15 as a result. Why? You need to think about the reason why the code does what it does, rather than just giving us your requirements.

Answer (score 3):

due to the fact that `minValue` is set to the value `0`, it means if you perform `Math.min(this.minValue, theValue);` the return value of this function call will always be `0` apart from when `theValue` is less than zero. to overcome the problem, change the `minValue` field from:

```
private int minValue;
```

to:

```
private int minValue = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
```

or better set both fields to:

```
private int maxValue = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
private int minValue = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
```

Also, the initialisations within the constructor were redundant, and are now wrong. You can remove the constructor entirely.

Answer (score 1):

It’s because you already call `minValue=0` at the beginning. Simply say: `minValue=Integer.MaxValue;` and `maxValue=Integer.MinValue;`